# Firebase tools use cases

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

could somebody explain use cases for using [firebase tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools). I understand that we can use them to connect to Firebase Realtime database and for authentication. But what I cannot grasp is: do we use it on our local machine and then deploy to google or is it also useful when hosting on other servers? I would love to hear more use cases for using the tools.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase tools/CLI provide commands to interact with your Firebase projects from a shell/terminal.

You'd typically run it on your local machine to make changes to the database, update files for hosting, update your security rules, import/export users, etc.

For a full list of its commands, see the [reference documentation for the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/).